# Duan 1995 GARCH option pricing model (and R)

Tags: r, garch, finance

I added similar question to Stackoverflow, but I am not sure if it's more of a code related or model specification question.

I want to replicate the below model of option pricing, from Duan's paper (1995) , using `rugarch` library in R.

[image]

I have two problems though:

1. I cannot find how to add the $-1/2 * s^2_t$ in the mean model when specifying it with `ugarchspec` function.
2. I cannot find to which GARCH family Duan's model belongs. The closest I found from `rugarch` documentation was the family GARCH (fGARCH) which is the following:

[image]

With $λ=δ=2$ and $η_{1j} = 0$ it's almost the same specification, but fGARCH uses standardized residuals $z_{t-j}$ where as Duan uses the unstandardized ones.

Any ideas on how I can replicate the model? It might need some transformation or it's not possible to use R for this calculation?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "replicating" a model?  What do you want to do with it?  What are you calculating?

Comment: I am trying to use S&P index returns to obtain, using the above model, the coefficients . Then I want to use the obtained variance to calculate options prices, using MC for creating different paths for the disturbance term and backtest them. To be exact I am following the paper of Lehar et.al (GARCH vs stochastic volatility: Option pricing and risk management) but they use Duan's model.  Of course I could use different mean and GARCH models and calculate the variance needed, but I was wondering if I can follow this specific one.